# Tengo una variable dentro de una estructura y al momento de compararla dentro de un if, no me funciona correctamente

Tags: c, funciones, condiciones

Al momento de llegar al

```
if(sensor[1].temperatura > 100){
           
           
           
               printf("Sensor sobrecalentado");
               
           }
```

El printf no se muestra en pantalla y no sé la razón.

Este es el código completo:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct{
       int sensor;
       double temperatura;
       char *estatus;
    }sensores;
    
    int temp;
    


int main () {

     sensores sensor[10];
     int i;
     for (i=1;i<3;i++){
     
     printf("\nIngrese el numero identificador del sensor: ");
     scanf("%i", &sensor[i].sensor);
     printf("\nIngrese la temperatura del sensor %i: ", i,sensor[i].sensor);
     scanf("%d", &sensor[i].temperatura);
     
     printf("La temperatura del sensor %i es %i", i,sensor[i].temperatura);


     }
     
     printf("\n%i\n",sensor[1].temperatura);
     system("pause");
     
     
     printf("la temperatura del primer sensor es %i", sensor[1].temperatura);
     
     system("pause");
     
     
     estatus(sensor);


     

return 0;
}



 void estatus(sensores sensor[]){
 
 
           printf(" la temperatura dentro de estatus es %i", sensor[1].temperatura);
           
           
           
           
           if(sensor[1].temperatura > 100){
           
           
           
               printf("Sensor sobrecalentado");
               
           }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 }
```
````

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en esta línea:

```c
scanf("%d", &sensor[i].temperatura);
```

El miembro `temperatura` es de tipo `double` y estás leyendo un `int` cuando en realidad debería ser un `double`.

**Solución:** Debes usar el especificador `%lf` en el primer parámetro del `scanf`:

```c
scanf("%lf", &sensor[i].temperatura);
```

Y por cierto, para imprimir (con `printf`) un dato de tipo `double`, debes usar el especificador `%f` o `%lf`.

Por ejemplo, en esta línea:

```c
printf("La temperatura del sensor %i es %i", i, sensor[i].temperatura);
```

Usas el especificador `%i` y eso está mal, puesto es para enteros y el miembro `temperatura` es de tipo `double`.

Aquí deberías usar `%f`:

```c
printf("La temperatura del sensor %i es %f", i, sensor[i].temperatura);
```